# Progress ODBC-Driver (Error 10713)

Tags: odbc, driver, openedge, progress-db

i have a Problem sending SQL-Queries over the Progress ODBC Driver to the Server. As soon as the tablename contains a "_" the driver aborts with the given error, when there is no "_" in the tablename everything seems to be fine.

[Here is a Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4ee9.png)

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Position - works

SELECT * FROM Position_logs - doesnt work
```

I`m using Flyspeed SQL to create the Queries.

Im thankful for any help

Comment: The pictured error message refers to WORK_ORDER and sysindex.  What does that have to do with Position_logs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the table name.

```
select * from 'Position_logs'
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying a schema; have you set a default schema prior to the query?  If not, you need to qualify your table names.  E.g.:
    select * from pub."position_logs";